# JSON Encode generates error when sending string that ends in ==

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to return a 1717 long token, that ends with "==" using php to Ajax.

In PHP I am returning the value as so:

```
echo json_encode($token);
```

In Javascript the Ajax is:

```
$.ajax({ 
                type: "GET",
            dataType:"JSON",
            url: myajax.ajax_url,
            data:{
                action: "get_token"
            },
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data){

            console.log(data);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                console.warn(jqXHR.responseText) 
                alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus +" :: " +errorThrown);

            }
    });
```

The error I am recieving is:

SyntaxError: Unexpected Number in Json at position 1718

I have look at the PHP logs and the token matches what is shown in the error message in chrome, but I still get this message.

I can take a random number and it will go through fine, but if i use the generated token it fails.

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Does `json_encode()` return `string` or `false`? And wouldn't it be crucial to your question to **ADD** just json around char `1718`?

Comment: Returns true, i can print it to the error log. Upon further examination, it looks like the function or tranmission is adding a 0 to the end of the encoding. So it appears  "encodeddata"0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I am in the Wordpress Framework and that requires to use wp_send_json() to return the currect value, otherwise it was adding a 0 to the end of the json data causing an error.

Correct statement should be:

```
echo wp_send_json($token);
```

Comment: That would be, assuming he is using [tag:wordpress] as I don't see it in his tags.